# Cannot get modal to Popup again - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently introducing myself to AngularJS and I am writing code for a button which when clicked would pop up a modal. The modal pops up nicely. When I click the 'X' on the modal, it goes away as well. The boolean which when set to false so as to make the modal pop up becomes true again, everything goes smoothly BUT the modal does not pop up the second time around. Why is this happening?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default" value="Path">{{showModal}}
<modal title="Select a Testcase" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form" >
        <div class="form-group" style="padding: 5%">
            <div id="tree_div"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</modal>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$scope.showModal =  false;

        $scope.toggleModal = function(){
            $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        };
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chariot').directive('modal', function () {
   return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
         '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
               '<div class="modal-header">' +
                  '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                  '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
               '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
         '</div>' +
         '</div>' +
         '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.title = attrs.title;

         scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
            if(value == true)
               $(element).modal('show');
            else
               $(element).modal('hide');
         });

         $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
               scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
            });
         });

         $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
               scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
            });
         });
      }
   };
});
```

I am stuck on this for hours! Is there something that I am missing? Any insight would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use object and not simple value for `$scope.showModal`. Example:

Controller:

```
$scope.showModal =  {visible: false};

$scope.toggleModal = function(){
    $scope.showModal.visible = !$scope.showModal.visible;
};
```

View:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default" value="Path">{{showModal}}
<modal title="Select a Testcase" show-modal="showModal">
    <form role="form" >
        <div class="form-group" style="padding: 5%">
            <div id="tree_div"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</modal>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('chariot').directive('modal', function () {
   return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
         '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
               '<div class="modal-header">' +
                  '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                  '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
               '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
         '</div>' +
         '</div>' +
         '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:{ 
          title: '@',
          showModal: '=',
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
         if( typeof( scope.showModal.visible ) === "undefined" ) {
              scope.showModal.visible = false;
         }
         scope.$watch('showModal.visible', function(value){
            if(value == true)
               $(element).modal('show');
            else
               $(element).modal('hide');
         });

         $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
               scope.showModal.visible = true;
            });
         });

         $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
               scope.showModal.visible = false;
            });
         });
      }
   };
});
```

When you bind to object to the directive, you can change its properties from the directives, and those changes will also be reflected to the controller.

Additional problem with your code was that its directive has  `replace: true` - So when you declare in your view `<modal title="Select a Testcase" show-modal="showModal">` - This data will be replaced by the directive html, and make the attribute no longer available.

To overcome this issue I made the directive to take the values from the scope, rather than the attributes by changing the mapping:

```
  scope:{ 
      title: '@',  // Use the title attribute value as a string
      showModal: '=', // use the "show-modal" attribute as an object
  },
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and now the modal is not popping up even once.

Comment: let me check it on jsfiddle

Comment: @SaniKul Can you check it now? I changed the directive scope from `title: '=',` to `title: '@',`

Comment: What? Why? How?! Please I want an explanation!

Comment: @SaniKul I added as much as I could (I think), My english isn't perfect so I hope It's clear enough

Comment: It was very helpful! Thank you so much!